# Quel serait l'équivalent de « one-size-fits-all » en contexte ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, locutions, emprunts

> Enfin, il faut se le dire : l’organisation scolaire proposée par notre
> système appartient à un autre temps. Particulièrement au secondaire,
> les horaires fixes, l’enseignement (et l’apprentissage) en silo, le
> ***one-size-fits-all*** et toute la rigidité associée appartiennent à un
> autre siècle. Il est temps de réfléchir à une expérience scolaire où
> le temps et l’espace répondent à des besoins pédagogiques et non
> l’inverse. (opinion ds. [*LaPresse*](https://www.lapresse.ca/debats/opinions/2023-02-03/education/et-si-on-s-attaquait-a-la-cause.php))

Comment peut-on remplacer le [*one-size-fits-all*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one-size-fits-all) (« (*figuratively, often derogatory*) Suitable for a wide range of tastes, opinions, situations, etc. », *Wiktionary*) ici et quel en est le référent sous-jacent ?

Answer (score 1):

Il semblerait que l'expression « *à tout faire* » convienne parfaitement.

> (TLFi)   − Loc. à valeur adj. **À tout faire**  Apte à toutes sortes de besognes.
> • Bonne à tout faire.
> • C'était Jeanne (...) qui avait indiqué Cadet comme un bon sujet, un garçon à tout faire, comme on dit (Sand, Jeanne,1844, p. 210).
> • Il arrive que le même mot, (comme liberté), s'emploie à des besognes d'expressions fort différentes. C'est un mot à tout faire (Valéry, Regards sur monde act.,1931, p. 246).

Le nom sous-entendu que cet adjectif nominalisé pourrait modifier étant assez vague, il en résulte que plusieurs options seront acceptables. Le terme « *système unique* » me semble un choix assez probable.

- Enfin, il faut se le dire : l’organisation scolaire proposée par notre système appartient à un autre temps. Particulièrement au secondaire, les horaires fixes, l’enseignement (et l’apprentissage) en silo, le système unique à tout faire et toute la rigidité associée appartiennent à un autre siècle.

« Système unique » serait à rapprocher de « *école unique* », « *classe unique* ».

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/unique)) **École unique**. ,,École qui serait la même pour tous les élèves, conduisant, seule, aux fins et aux objectifs définis par l'État, conformément à une conception valable pour tous, quels que soient les origines, les milieux sociaux, les croyances des enfants et des parents`` (Leif 1974).
> • Il expose ses idées pédagogiques, au sujet de l'éducation distinguée qu'il veut donner à son neveu (...) Ah! certes, il n'eût pas été partisan de l'école unique! (Rolland, Beethoven, t. 1, 1937, p. 54).
> • **Classe unique**, écoles à classe unique. Écoles ne comprenant qu'une seule classe dirigée par un seul maître, et recevant des enfants de six à onze ans, dans les milieux ruraux à faible population (d'apr. Leif 1974, s.v. école).
> • Dans le cas d'une classe enfantine annexée à une école mixte à classe unique ou à une école spéciale de filles à une classe, la classe enfantine pourra conserver les enfants de 6 à 7 ans (Encyclop. éduc., 1960, p. 99).

Comment: Merci, les deux sont utiles mais en composé je ne trouve pas _système unique à tout faire_ naturel. Aussi je trouve _à tout faire_ plus concret, comme justement _homme à tout faire_ et l'exemple de Valéry semble s'appuyer sur _besognes_ qui rend son propos étrangement terre à terre pour une raison que j'ignore (je n'en connais pas le contexte). Le référent _système_ est une possibilité, mais dans une liste avec des éléments plus spécifiques, peut-être que _solution_ est meilleur.

Answer (score 0):

Le caractère de ce qui conviendrait à une vaste gamme de choses, péjorativement, et qui s'opposerait au *sur mesure* ou aux besoins individuels relève aussi de l'*uniformité*, en plus de l'[*unicité*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/52351). Et dans une liste d'éléments de portées distinctes (*les horaires fixes, l'enseignement/l'apprentissage en silo, la rigidité*), un référent utile pourrait être « solution » et pour connoter mieux l'aspect négatif on pourrait utiliser le degré (*trop*, par exemple) et ça nécessiterait le pluriel (« les solutions trop uniformes ») ou le substantif (« trop d'uniformité ») et vu que c'est suivi par « (toute la) rigidité » on pourrait aussi avoir l'article (« l'uniformité excessive/à l'excès », « l'excès d'uniformité »).

Par ailleurs, j'ai trouvé l'emprunt intégral absolument stupéfiant vu le propos. Et entre celui-ci et une expression critiquée qui est influencée par l'anglais au Québec je choisirais cette dernière, soit le « [mur-à-mur](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/23288/les-emprunts-a-langlais/emprunts-idiomatiques/emplois-deconseilles-et-corrects-de-mur-a-mur) », seul ou avec *approche* (« le mur-à-mur », « une approche mur-à-mur »). Dans le même sens, je pense que je peux dire dans mon sociolecte, de manière familière, « à la grandeur » (« les mêmes solutions, à la grandeur »), possiblement un calque de « at large ».